# Product count of a subtree SQL nested set

Tags: sql, mysql, nested-sets

See http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Under the heading "Aggregate Functions in a Nested Set"

I'm trying to work out a query similar to the example given, except I want it to work at a sub-tree level, so if I queried for MP3 players I would get a result set like;

```
|NAME          |COUNT|
----------------------
|MP3 PLAYERS   |  2  | // 2 because 1 at this level and 1 at child level  
|FLASH PLAYERS |  1  |
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the self referencing table tree_node is created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tree_node
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  parent integer,
  "desc" text,
  l integer,
  r integer,
  CONSTRAINT tree_node_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The counts can be retrieved with the following SQL:

```
select count(*), p.id, p.desc from tree_node c, tree_node p
where c.l<=p.r
and c.l>=p.l
group by p.id, p.desc;
```

Comment: I want this node to potentially have multiple parents, so adding a parent field isn't ideal. 

I have the table structure defined at the above url. 


CREATE TABLE category(
category_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
parent INT DEFAULT NULL);

Comment: It works of the multiple parents are within a tree structure.  Querying shows the record, children, grand children, great grand children, etc, and the great grand children have multiple levels of parent data.  If this does not fulfill your requirements, please clarify the scenario.